# Use sed to find and replace a string in multiple files

Tags: sed, grep, find, for

I'm trying to pass a list of files with a known set of characters to sed for a find and replace.

For a directory containing multiple .xml files:

```
ls -la

file1.xml
file2.xml
file3.xml
```

Each containing a matching string:

```
grep -i foo *

file1.xml <foo/>
file2.xml <foo/>
file3.xml <foo/>
```

Replace foo with bar using a for loop:

```
for f in *.xml; do ls | sed -i "s|foo|bar|g" ; done
```

Returns:

```
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
```

I already figured out an alternative that works, so this is mostly for my own edification at this point.

```
find /dir/ -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i "s|foo|bar|g" {} \;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a flaw in your `for` loop.  Remove the `ls` command, and add the `$f` variable as the argument to `sed -i`, which will edit each `filename.xml` in place:

```
for f in *.xml; do sed -i "s|foo|bar|g" "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the GNU sed you can edit multiple files and in-place as well. So your task thus reduces to:

```
sed -i -se 's|foo|bar|g' *.xml
```

`-s for --separate` is the `sed` option that does it.

Answer (score 0):

sed is expecting the input path as a parameter. So try a construction as the following:

```
 … | sed -i "…" /dev/stdin
```

It would be even easier to use the files as parameter, as this (untested):

```
sed -i "..." *.xml
```